# Install Ubuntu to partition with Windows 7 Loader - erase partition with Win loader

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu

Can I install Ubuntu 9.10 to partition with Windows 7 Loader? I.e. I want to completely erase this partition and have Ubuntu on it. Will GRUB boot Windows 7 without its loader?

Windows 7 Loader is on C: while the system itself is on E:.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can [install Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) with Windows 7 pre-installed. Take a look at these notes on [dual-booting Windows 7 and Linux](http://www.arcfn.com/2009/11/notes-on-dual-booting-windows-7-and.html)  and [Adding Windows 7 to Linux Multi-boot](http://blog.lokonopa.com/grub-up-windows-7/).